# How to get notification about an MS Teams user's current call?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

How to get the  callId of an MSTeams user's current call after he answered it, using the MS Graph Call API?
Webhooks? in C# or Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This feature currently does not exist. You can request (or vote for) new features on [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/).